# Requests: Explanation of the .text format

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, python-requests

I'm using the `requests` module along with Python 2.7 to build a basic web crawler.

```
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
```

Now, in the above lines of code, I'm storing the source code of the specified URL and other metadata inside the `source_code` variable. Now, in `source_code.text`, what exactly is the `.text` attribute? It is not a function. I couldn't find anything in the documentation which explains the origin or feature of `.text` either.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requests.get()` returns a *[`Response` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response)*; it is that object that has the `.text` attribute; it is *not* the 'source code' of the URL, it is an object that lets you access the source code (the body) of the response, as well as other information. The `Response.text` attribute gives you the body of the response, decoded to `unicode`.

See the [*Response Content* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) of the Quickstart documentation:

> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers. The text encoding guessed by Requests is used when you access `r.text`.

Further information can be found in the API documentation, see the [`Response.text` entry](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.text):

> Content of the response, in unicode.
>
> If Response.encoding is None, encoding will be guessed using `chardet`.
>
> The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the encoding, you should set `r.encoding` appropriately before accessing this property.

You can also use [`Response.content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content) to access the response body undecoded, as raw bytes.

Comment: This answered all the questions I had, and more! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in this line

```
 source_code = requests.get(url)
```

`source_code` has a `response` object, not the source code.

it should be

```
response = requests.get(url)
source_code = response.text
```