# Why does variable could be added to'.json' and '.text'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
req=requests.get(json_url)
with open('xxx','w') as f:

    f.write(req.text)
file_requests=req.json()
```

requests is a module, get is a function, so req=requests.get(), but what is req.txt and req.json(), is it also a function?

Comment: `requests.get()` performs a get request to the specified URL, `req.text` is a property of the object returned by `requests.get` and `req.json()` is a builtin json decoder method of requests.

Comment: check out this docs [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: Welcome. You can see for `req.text` from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819483/requests-explanation-of-the-text-format#34819497) and for req.json() from [link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
requests.get(json_url)
```

return python object(http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response)

`requests.Response`:

- has methods `json` (return http-body as json)
- has attribute(text and content)

May be it is property, (read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0549/)